# Extensible Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I am new to Orchard, I am wondering how Can I run my module once project start instead of Orchard Startup module?
Also how can I override the Routing to route to my new module?where it is being written?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement IHomePageProvider. If I understood the question.